# Update Banco de Dados Android

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Estou criando um Banco de Dados no Android que tem uma coluna chamada status onde está salvando (0 ou 1) 0 para quando estiver sem internet e 1 para quando tiver com internet, quero fazer o *update* do banco para que ocorra o seguinte, quando voltar a internet no celular na coluna status o que estiver salvo com 0 passe a está com 1! em linguagem SQL ficaria assim:

```
update nomeTabela set status='1' where status='0'
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é a sua dúvida? Edite sua pergunta e cole o código diretamente. Do modo como está fica muito difícil de fazer qualquer tipo de teste.

Comment: Prefira códigos à imagens!

Comment: Poste códigos, imagens são mais complicadas de se analisar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se for apenas para rodar aquele comando você poderia fazer parecido com o que está no Insert:

```
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues, String selection,
                      String[] selectionArgs) {
    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();

    int rowsUpdated = 0;

    rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(DATABASE_TABLE,
                    contentValues, selection, selectionArgs);

    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);
    return rowsUpdated;
}
```

A chamada ao método deve vir já com o ponteiro posicionado no registro que você deseja atualizar. Isso é feito pela seleção da URI com um contentResolver().

A minha função é uma saveState, vou postar ela, talvez te ajude, mas eu recomendo que você entenda melhor como funciona o ContentProvider, pois este update que você propôs sempre irá atualizar todos os registros da sua tabela. Eh esse o comportamento esperado?

```
private void saveState() {
        String categoria = (String)mCategoria.getSelectedItem();
        String descricao = (String)mDescricaoText.getText().toString();
        String valor = mValorText.getText().toString();
        String parcelas = mParcelasText.getText().toString();
        String dataInclusao = mDataInclusao.getText().toString();
        String dataVencimento = mDataVencimento.getText().toString();

        if(descricao.length() == 0 && valor.length() == 0){
            return;
        }

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(LancamentoTable.COLUMN_DESCRICAO, descricao);
        values.put(LancamentoTable.COLUMN_VALOR, valor);
        values.put(LancamentoTable.COLUMN_PARCELAS, parcelas);
        values.put(LancamentoTable.COLUMN_ID_CATEGORIA, categoria);
        values.put(LancamentoTable.COLUMN_DATA_INCLUSAO, dataInclusao);
        values.put(LancamentoTable.COLUMN_DATA_VENCIMENTO, dataVencimento);
        values.put(LancamentoTable.COLUMN_SINAL, (categoria.toString().equals("DEBITO") ? "-1" : "1"));

        if(todoUri==null){
            todoUri = getContentResolver().insert(SmartBillContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
        } else {
            getContentResolver().update(todoUri, values, null, null);
        }
    }
```

Meu código é de iniciante, não tenho grande experiência em Android, portanto recomendo o link abaixo como uma boa base para trabalhar com SQLite no Android:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html